Question about intact of Islam
Assalamu alaikum. I am suffering from waswas.I am confused have I commited shirk or not.I got a fatwa that is if I am not certain,
Certainity of Islam is not affected by doubt,my islam is intact.Now my question is if I am confused due to forgetfulness(from shaytan or myself),is my Islam still intact?

One can't answer that without more info.
What makes you think you left islam?
Are you having shirk thoughts?
do you believe in those thoughts?
If if you just having waswas from shaytan but you don't believe them or act on them then you are fine and islam is 100 percent accurate and you are a Muslim without a doubt.
Sahaba use to have these thoughts. One of the sahaba went to prophet peace and blessing be upon him and said " I have bad thoughts about Allah, I feel disgusted to even speak or think about it" prophet peace and blessings be upon him replied "this is the sign of iman".
Reason was shaytan will only come to those who have strong iman as he want to misguided you. If you are already misguided why would shaytan bother you.
As long as you don't believe in them or act upon the waswas your are fine.
Do alot of adhkar, whenever u have waswas say "amantu billahi wa rasulihi" and "audhubillah min al-shaytaan ir-rajeem". Make alot of dua in your sujood. Have muslim knowledgeable friends.
Inshallah you will be OK. Make sure you make dua for me as well.
May Allah protect us from shaytan and his tricks, keep us steadfast on Iman and allow us to die with iman in our heart.
